# Can this order relation, defined in terms of all topological spaces, be defined in terms of the reals alone?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, order-theory, posets, modal-logic

Let $K$ be the operator monoid under composition of Kuratowski's $14$ set operators generated by topological closure $k$ and complement $c.$ Kuratowski's 1922 paper gives the poset diagram of the ordering $\preceq$ on $K$ defined by:

$$x\preceq y\iff xA\subseteq yA\text{ for all subsets }A\text{ in every topological space.}$$ This poset appears below up to duality where $i$ denotes the interior operator and id the identity operator.

Given a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ let $\leq_{(X,\mathcal{T})}$ be the ordering on $K$ defined by:

$$x\leq_{(X,\mathcal{T})}y\iff xA\subseteq yA\text{ for all }A\subseteq X.$$

Obviously every $(X,\mathcal{T})$ satisfies the implication $x\preceq y\implies x\leq_{(X,\mathcal{T})}y$ but is there any theorem that guarantees the existence (i.e., we can know in advance before setting out to find an example) of a space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ such that $x\preceq y\iff x\leq_{(X,\mathcal{T})}y?$

Of course, we already know that $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual topology is such an example for $K.$

There is a famous theorem of McKinsey and Tarski that says two set operators $x$ and $y$ expressible in terms of $c,$ $k,$ $i,$ $\wedge,$ and $\vee$ where $(x\wedge y)A:=xA\cap yA$ and $(x\vee y)A:=xA\cup yA$ are equal on every topological space if and only if they are equal on every finite topological space if and only if they are equal on $\mathbb{R}$ (under the usual topology).

So perhaps the following is a better way to state my question:

Do we have

$$x\preceq y\iff x\leq_{\mathbb{R}}y$$

for all $x$ and $y$ composed from $c,$ $k,$ $i,$ $\wedge,$ and $\vee?$

[image]

Comment: For the first question, can't we just take the disjoint sum of spaces realizing the various separations individually? Within each part, the terms act the same, and so the terms will be separated this way all in one space.

Comment: I can’t make sense of the question. We do have $x\preceq y\iff x\le_{\mathbb R}y$ by the McKinsey–Tarski completeness theorem (which, by the way, holds more generally for any nonempty dense-in-itself separable metrizable space in place of $\mathbb R$) that you quote in the preceding paragraph. So why do you reask it as a question?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek thanks that's all I was curious about.  I just wasn't familiar enough with the completeness theorem to know it covers this.

Comment: I knew it covers equality but didn't know it covers the more general $\leq$.  When I can get my hands on a copy I expect this 2018 paper on the theorem will help me up my game: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11225-018-9789-5

Comment: Oh, I’m so used to the fact that in such contexts $\le$ and $=$ are equivalent that I didn’t spot the difference. So, $\le$ can be reduced to $=$ in one of several trivial ways: $x\le y\iff x\land y=x\iff x\lor y=y\iff c(x)\lor y=1\iff x\land c(y)=0$ (where the constant operators $0$ and $1$ evaluate to $\varnothing$ and the whole space, respectively; you can define these from the other operators).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek thanks, now I get it finally: my paragraph about McKinsey-Tarski answers the question.  I'm not very used to this context so it escaped my notice.